# Batch file fails to run all lines when called from task manager

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, batch-file, task-scheduler

I have a .bat file that consists of 450 lines of:
start [executable] [params]

Presently all the lines are perfectly identical. If I run the bat file manually, I end up with 450 instances of the executable running. If I set up a task in task scheduler and run that, I get between 100 and 120 instances of the executable running.

I have made sure to set the job to run with highest priviledges, but other than that, I don't have much idea as to why it will only successfully execute 1 in 4 of the start calls. Task manager it self will return no error, nor is there anything in the event viewer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after some more trial and error, it would seem like adding the /b flag to each line will cause all of them to be correctly instantiated.

Just leaving this here in case anyone else encounters the same issue.